# How to get all drives directories C#

Tags: c#, directory

I want to get all drives directories and put them in a list box without system getting crashed.

I've tried this codes but I get a not responding! Even once that program do the task complete I had only the d drive dirs in the list box!

```
foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
{
    if (drive.Name != Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory))
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(drive.Name, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried this codes but I get a not responding

Well yeah, you put an extreme amount of work on the UI thread, of course the UI is not responding. Put it on a background thread instead and have it interact with the UI through message posting (`BeginInvoke` and such).

> Even once that program do the task complete I had only the d drive dirs in the list box!

Again, yeah, you're excluding the system drive in your query, which is presumably `C:\`

```
if (drive.Name != Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory))
```

Comment: Read up on Background Worker Threads in C#.  There's lots of documentation online about this.  Best of luck.